# Is there a JS /PHP (not Node.js related) library to support blogging?

Tags: library, javascript, html, php, blog

The client already has a relatively popular web site, coded in JS/PHP/ HTML5/CSS3 some years ago. For a variety of reasons they don't want to switch to CMS platforms like WordPress, Wix or Joomla etc.

However they do want to add a blog to their site. I suggested to redirect a blog link of their site to a 3rd party platform, like Blogger. They do not like it either.

So I started to look around for JS/PHP libraries that support blogging, something like phpBB for forums that may be incorporated into almost any site. Unfortunately I couldn't find even a single one. [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) is the closest thing that I found, but it requests Node.js

Any recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your client seems not to be aware that CMSes and blogging engines overlap substantially, WordPress being the most obvious example. Why doesn't he want a CMS? If he's against all the GUI fanciness of CMSes, then shouldn't he be using raw HTML or a simple templating engine or static-site generator?

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found something: [couchCMS](https://www.couchcms.com)

It is called CMS, but actually it is a kind of the programming framework, more or less what I was looking for. You can add it to any existing site without a need to rerwite it.